# Hibernate Schema-validation: missing column [q] in table x

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Hi I am trying to execute native sql query on mysql from hibernate.
Raw sql below work fine with terminal

```
select (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(my_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(my_longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(my_latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude)))) AS distance FROM address a HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance
```

But when i used it with repository i am getting exception

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [q] in table [address]`

My Address entity as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends Auditable<String> {


    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Double latitude;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    private Double longitude;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String address;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private User user;
}
```

My NearByDto as below:

```
public interface NearByDto {
    Long getId();
    String getAddress();
    Double getDistance();
}
```

Repository is as below:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(my_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(my_longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(my_latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude)))) AS distance FROM address a HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance", nativeQuery = true)
    List<NearByDto> findNearby();

}
```

Auditable

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Auditable<U> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;


    @CreatedBy
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    protected U createdBy;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Date creationDate;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    protected U lastModifiedBy;


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Date lastModifiedDate;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    protected Boolean isActive;

}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends Auditable<String> implements UserDetails {
    ....
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Address> addresses;
    ....
}
```

*For reference

my_latitude = latitude in query string

my_longitude = hardcoded_longitude in query string

Comment: Please also provide us the Auditable<T> class.

Comment: @DinaBogdan i have added auditable class, please take a look.

Comment: And also it will be useful to provide the User class.

Comment: added user class

Comment: Do you have somewhere a column that is named "Q" ?

Comment: NO i don't have any such column thats why i getting confused

Comment: Your tables are created by Hibernate or you have manually created your tables ?

Comment: Initially i have create using autogeneration, then using flyway with V1__init.sql as this first ddl script

Comment: I am so so so so so so silly, there was a field called String q="this long sql which is added in model class to study and it caused the hell lot of damage :/"

Comment: Then you have figure out the problem :) perfect!

Comment: Yes, executing test, once able to fetch then will update my noobness :/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after going through basics i got it working.

I have field name String q="@Query(...long...sql)" in my domain model.
`hibernate:ddl-auto: validate` was validate and i have not written a script to add this newly created field my mistake, it was rightly a proper message from hibernate.

My updated repository is as follow along with dynamic latitude, longitude and radius:

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select a.id, a.address, (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(:latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(a.longitude) - RADIANS(:longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(:latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(a.latitude)))) AS distance FROM address a HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance", nativeQuery = true)
    List<NearByDto> findNearbyGangs(Double latitude, Double longitude, Double radius);

}
```

Thanks @dina for guiding me through step by step as i lost the changes i did in many files.